# Python openCV - error displaying an image from webcam

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am a beginner with OpenCV and Python, doing my first steps...
I am trying to run a test code written in Python using OpenCv. I am getting an error saying :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3402
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\cam.py", line 11, in <module>
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3402: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4
```

It will run in the IDLE(Python GUI) but, I am trying to run it in VS2010 with the Python plugin - that is where i get the error.
Any advice on how to handle this error highly appreciated.

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Probably a bug with vs2010 if it runs fine from IDLE.

Comment: Not really because I tried to run it from the cmd and same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out...

adding

```
cap.read()
```

after the

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

fixes the problem...